# How can I safely remove an npm init done in the wrong folder?

Tags: npm, directory, init

This is my first ever question around here so please be kind :)).
I went to the wrong folder in the terminal and hit: npm init .
So there's a package.json doing nothing in there and never will do.
I couldn't find anything about uninstalling safely from just a directory.
Can anyone safely guide me through an uninstall please?

Comment: `rm package.json` 

Comment: Thank you! I did that! :) Worked fine! Just wondering if there is anything more to an npm init than just creating the package.json ?

Comment: No, unless you do also `npm install` which can create `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. The `npm init` is just an easy way to create the baseline of a `package.json` file but you could do manually the same too.